# The integral of a function that is 0 a.e is 0

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

I am working on this problem:
Let $f = 0$ for all $x \in [a,b] $ except for $x$ in a set of Lebesgue measure zero. Then $\int_a^b f \,dx = 0$ if the integral exists.

Here are my ideas: Split $f$ into its positive part and negative part so that $f = f^+ + f^- = f^+ - (-f^-)$. Then both $f^+$ and $-f^-\geq 0$. Then since $L(P,f) \leq \sigma(P,f) \leq U(P,f) $ for any partition $P$ of $[a,b]$ and any Riemann sum $\sigma$, then I just need to show that for any  $P$ there is a Riemann sum over $P$ equal to $0$. So partition $[a,b]$ as $P: a = x_0 < ... < x_n = b$. Then it suffices to show that each subinterval $[x_{i-1},x_i]$ is not contained in the set of measure zero.

And here is where I am stuck. If I  assume that $[x_{i-1},x_i]$ is part of that set, then I know each subinterval must also have measure zero, but I don't know how to use this to achieve a contradiction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are dealing with the Riemann integral, I assuming that $f$ is bounded on $[a,b]$ (otherwise the Riemann integral would not exist).

I am using the notation: If $I$ is an interval, then  $m I = \sup I - \inf I$ (that is, the length).

We need the following result:
If a compact set $C$ has measure zero, then it has content zero. That is, for any $\epsilon>0$, there is a **finite** collection of intervals $I_k$ with $\sum_k mI_k < \epsilon$ such that $C \subset \cup_k I_k$.

Let $|f|$ be bounded by $B$.

Let $\epsilon>0$. Then let $I_k$ be a finite  cover of $[a,b]$ by intervals such that $\sum m I_k < \frac{1}{B}\epsilon$. Without loss of generality, we may take the intervals to be closed (since $m I_k = m \overline{I}_k$) and non overlapping (if they overlap, just replace them by their union, and since $m (I_k \cup I_j) \le m I_k + m I_j$, the conditions are still satisfied).

Since the $I_k$ are non-overlapping closed intervals, we can assume they are in 
increasing order (that is, if $ x \in I_k$, $y \in I_{k+1}$, then $ x< y$). 
Let $I_k = [a_k,b_k]$. Then form the partition $\pi=(a,a_1,b_1,...,a_n,b_n,b)$.

Then $L(f,\pi) = \sum_k \inf f(I_k) m I_k$ (since $f$ is zero on the complement of $\cup I_k$), and so we have $L(f,\pi) \ge \sum_k (-B) m I_k > \epsilon$.

Similarly, we have $U(f,\pi) = \sum_k \sup f(I_k) m I_k \le\sum_k B m I_k  < \epsilon$.

Since $\epsilon>0$ was arbitrary, we have $\sup_{\pi \in {\cal P}} L(f,\pi) = \inf_{\pi \in {\cal P}} U(f,\pi) = 0$, and so $\int_a^b f = 0$.

Comment: I had thought about this, but I am not sure if this is valid. $\forall \epsilon > 0$, we can cover $[x_{i-1},x_{i}]$ by $(x_{i-1}- \epsilon, x_i + \epsilon)$. So this means $2 \epsilon + \Delta x_i < \epsilon $, which is impossible as all quantities are positive.

Comment: @user105932: The result I stated is valid, and is trivial to prove. I'm not sure what you are trying to say. The set $[x_{i-1},x_i]$ has measure zero **iff** $x_{i-1} = x_i$.

Comment: Sorry, I know your result was valid. Above was a (failed) attempt at trying to apply it to get a contradiction for my problem.

I am trying to see why $[x_{i-1},x_i]$ has measure zero iff $x_{i-1} = x_i$, and I am not getting it. Could you possibly explain this in more detail?

Comment: The measure of $[x_{i-1},x_i]$ is $(x_i-x_{i-1})$? Its just the length of an interval.

Comment: Oh, I did not know this. My textbook has only defined what it means for a set to have measure zero, I did not realize the measure of an interval is simply its length.

Comment: Presumably it says that a set is of measure zero if for all $\epsilon>0$  it can be covered by a countable collection of intervals whose sum of lengths are less than $\epsilon$? I just use $m$ for the length (since the Lebesgue measure of an interval is the same as its length, but that's not relevant here). Replace all my $m$s above by length or whatever you are used to.

Comment: I added a note to that effect above.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the help. Now I am just trying to make sure I understand definitions thoroughly. 

Suppose I want to show that $[a,b]$ doesnt have measure 0 using only the definition of measure 0. if $[a,b]$ did have measure 0, then there would be finitely many $I_i$ such that the sum of all $|I_i| < \epsilon$. But then as $[a,b]$ is contained in this union, its length must be $\leq$ than the sum of the length of each individual $I_i$, so $\implies |[a,b]| < \epsilon$, for all $\epsilon > 0$, which is impossible as a < b.
Does this work?

Comment: I would argue as follows: Suppose $I_k$ are open intervals that cover $[a,b]$. Since $[a,b]$ is compact, a finite number of intervals cover $[a,b]$. Then you need to show that $\sum l(I_k) \ge b-a$ ($l$ is the length of the interval).

Comment: To do this, note that if $I_j \cap I_k \ne \emptyset$, then $l(I_k) + l(I_j) \ge l(I_j \cup I_k)$, and $I_j \cup I_k$ is also an interval. So we can continue doing this until the remaining intervals are disjoint. However, since $[a,b]$ is connected, this means that there is exactly one interval $I$ left, and since $[a,b] \subset I$, we have $l([a,b]) =b-a \le l(I)$. And by construction, $l(I) \le \sum_k l(I_k)$.